# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined (ngrx)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using ngrx. I got error

> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

This is part of my codes:

```
@Effect() foo$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(Actions.FOO)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({ action, state }))
    .map(({ action, state }) => {
      if (state.foo.isCool) {
        return { type: Actions.BAR };
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is little tricky since it is not easy to locate the issue based on the error.

In this situation, when `state.foo.isCool` is `false`, no action is returned.

So changing to something like this will solve the issue:

```
@Effect() foo$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(Actions.FOO)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({ action, state }))
    .map(({ action, state }) => {
      if (state.foo.isCool) {
        return { type: Actions.BAR };
      }

      return { type: Actions.SOMETHING_ELSE };
    });
```

Comment: I observed, many times you ask question and answer by yourself that is within 5 min only.

Comment: @micronyks yeah you can answer your own question when you ask. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @micronyks I saw a lot of people running into this issue when using ngrx. I guess I'd better provide an solution here instead of helping them seperately again and again which spends me extra time.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't answer yourself. But it seems you are doing it purposefully to help people. Nevermind do it. I don't mind. I just said what I observed.

Comment: "In your situation...You forgot...." you understand that u answer to your question? lol

Comment: @StavAlfi just reword